# Name-spaced JavaScript wrapped in self executing function

Tags: javascript

Is there any point in wrapping this code in the self executing function declaring window and undefined? I've read that it improves performance etc... (NOTE I will be making use of the window at some point).

```
(function (window, undefined) { // THIS BIT HERE!
  var App = {
    init: (function () {
      $(document).ready(function () {
        App.alertMessage('Hello world');
      });
    })(),
    alertMessage: function (message) {
      alert(message);
    }
  }
})(window); // end closure
```

Comment: If all you ask is why are those two arguments declared, then I think @dystroy's answer puts it simply. If you're also asking why the self-executing function in the first place: it prevents you from polluting the global object with variables you declare with `var`s.

Answer (score 1):

## The IIFE/SEFE/closure/whatever

A quick discussion why we use "closures" for creating our code is that the purpose of the closure/IIFE/SEFE/whatever you want to call it, is to provide a scope where you are free to declare any variables for the internals to use, without polluting the global scope:

```
(function(ns){

  //I can declare tons of variables and functions here
  var a,b,c,d,e,f,g ...;

  //expose only foo to the namespace
  ns.foo = function(){
    //and foo can use them here
  }

}(this.myNS = this.myNS || {}));

//but out here, we call foo, use those variables
//but none of those variables are visible
myNS.foo();

//no a,b,c,d,e,f,g ... out here
```

## `window`

Now, in the case of `window`, the idea that they are passed into the function is to have a local reference of whatever was pointed by them. It's because of the usage of that IIFE/SEFE/closure and how the compiler works.

```
//-3-found "a" here
var a = 1
(function(ns){
  //-2-no "a" here, going up
  ns.foo = function(){
    //-1-no "a" here, going up
    console.log(a);
  }
}(this.myNS = this.myNS || {}));

myNS.foo();
```

A quick trip into the how the compiler works is that when it tries to look for a variable/function, it searches through the local function scope first. If that variable/function is not found, it will look for it in the outer/containing scope. This goes on until the compiler finds that value or when you reach the global scope and declares it as non-existent.

In the code above, you crossed 2 scopes in order to find `a`. If `a` was declared lower into the scope, you could have minimized crossings. Now, wouldn't it be better if you provided window locally instead of having the compiler find it? YES, although:

- performance gain is almost negligible
- code structure might be more important than this minor optimization

## `undefined`

For `undefined`, it's because `undefined` is mutable (it's not constant/final). Its value *can* be changed so that it would not be `undefined` anymore (but somewhat "pseudo-defined"). A quick code about that [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/easierbycode/1953667):

```
var a = {};
a.b === undefined; // true because property b is not set
undefined = 42;
a.b === undefined; // false, because undefined is something else
```

So what they did to overcome this "definable `undefined`" was to pass nothing into the function, and by default, passing nothing to the function and naming it something in the function gives it the value of "true `undefined`".

---

Personally, I don't pass in `window` and `undefined` into my closure for some reasons:

- I don't check potentially undefined values against `undefined`. Since undefined values are falsy, loose comparison will tell if it is undefined or more like "unusable":

  ```
  //instead of this:
  if(potentiallyUndefined === undefined){...do stuff...}
  if(typeof potentiallyUndefined === 'undefined'){...do stuff...}

  //you can do this
  if(potentiallyUndefined){...do stuff...}
  ```
- Like I said, it's a minor/negligible performance gain, so I don't pass in `window`. Besides, how much of my code uses `window` anyway?

Comment: Adding a little to your answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567055/immutable-undefined-in-self-invoking-functions

Answer (score 0):

There is only one positive result that I know : it lets minifiers replace `window` and `undefined` with shorter names.